# Como fazer um cadastro múltiplo

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Boa noite, tenho um formulário dinâmico que envia o seguinte form:

```
plano_nome: Unimed                     //nome do plano

tipo_especializacao[]: protese         // 1º tipo de especializaçao do plano
plano_tratamento[]: Teste 1            // 1º tratamento do plano
plano_tratamento_valor[]: 23           // 1º valor
plano_usar[]: on                       // se esta ativo ou não  

tipo_especializacao[]: protese         // 2º tipo de especializaçao do plano
plano_tratamento[]: Teste 2            // 2º tratamento do plano
plano_tratamento_valor[]: 32           // 2º valor
plano_usar[]: on                       // se esta ativo ou não
```

E recebo em meu model com o seguinte código:

```
public function addPlanos($postData)
{

    $dataPlano = array
    (
        'plano_nome' => $postData['plano_nome']
    );

    $this->db->insert('planos', $dataPlano);
    $insert_id = '';

    if ($this->db->affected_rows() == 1)
    {
        $insert_id = $this->db->insert_id();
        $success = 0;

        $plano_tratamento = explode(",", $postData['plano_tratamento']);
        $plano_tratamento_valor = explode(",", $postData['plano_tratamento_valor']);
        $plano_usar = explode(",", $postData['plano_usar']);
        $tipo_especializacao = explode(",", $postData['tipo_especializacao']);

        for ($i=0; $i < count($plano_tratamento); $i++)
        {
            $data = array
            (
                'plano_tratamento' => trim($plano_tratamento[$i], ','), 
                'plano_tratamento_valor' => trim($plano_tratamento_valor[$i], ','), 
                'plano_usar' => trim($plano_usar[$i], ',') == 'on'? 'S' : 'N', 
                'tipo_especializacao' => trim($tipo_especializacao[$i], ','),
                'id_plano'  => $insert_id 
            );

            $this->db->insert('tratamentos', $data);
            $success += $this->db->affected_rows();
        }

        if ($success > 0)
        {
            return  array('type' => 'success', 'title' => 'Oba!!!', 'text' => 'Plano cadastrado com sucesso!');      
        }
        else
        {
            return  array('type' => 'danger', 'title' => 'Opss!!!', 'text' => 'Erro ao realizar o cadastro! <br> Tente novamente ou entre em contato <br> com o Admistrador do Sistema!');
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return  array('type' => 'danger', 'title' => 'Opss!!!', 'text' => 'Erro ao realizar o cadastro! <br> Tente novamente ou entre em contato <br> com o Admistrador do Sistema!');
    }    
}
```

Porém está dando erro, esta apenas cadastrando um, ou da erro no explode.
Minha logica no model era cadastrar primeiramente o plano (isso está acontecendo) e depois retornar seu id para fazer o cadastro dos tratamentos.
Na logica que eu buscava ele tinha que cadastrar o 1º e depois fazer o seguinte, porém como disse não está ocorrendo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creio que o problema está na sua variável `$insert_id`. Como a variável não está sendo atualizada no laço for, quando o programa tenta inserir o segundo tratamento ele utiliza o mesmo id do anterior, o que causa o erro.

Tente modificar o valor de `$insert_id` em cada  iteração do laço for.

Comment: Na vdd ele não pode ser alterado amigo, pois os tratamentos são do mesmo plano entendeu, ele cadastra o plano e retorna id pra assim cadastrar os tratamentos.

Comment: Ah... então o $insert_id é uma chave estrangeira que faz referência ao plano... entendi... Só dá pra ajudar se você enviar o var_dump do seu $postData.